# Magento 2: Is there any way to use 3rd party ( External ) url for showing product image?

Tags: magento2

I just need to use product image from 3rd party url. Is there any way to do this?

I am not able to use default magento import functionality because my product image size is above 1TB and product is above 600k . so i am not able do this thing.

Any idea please share..

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: @mahmoudismail We have used the s3 amazon bucket so all media storage coming from bucket.

Comment: well noted, thank you for your reply. But do you use the default import for images?

Comment: @mahmoudismail no, because, in default import functionality always used to relative path like (a/b/abc.jpg), if you set 3rd partyurl in csv file then also its convert into relative path after imported in magento. For use this 3rd party url you have to customized the  code for that & may be helpful of this s3 bucket extension that is available in github. So you can get better idea about how can you achieve this.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for your useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can import images from 3rd party url using the default csv import. Just go to **Magento2 Dashboard > System > Import** and add your csv file. In the column where you would put **imageName.jpg** you add the **3rd-party-url/imageName.jpg**. More info [here](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html).

Comment: my product image size is above 1TB  and  product is above 600k . so i am not able do this thing

Comment: Edit the original question with this information because it's relevant and that amount of data cannot be imported using default importer.